# Linking on 0 or more missing data fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a huge master table (1tb of data),  and over 20 columns.  I have source data comming in with 0 or more missing data fields.  I have to fill in the missing data by matching the available fields in the master table.  Please consider the following example:

Incoming Data:

```
 CREATE TABLE #t1 ( f3 VARCHAR(50), f1 INT, f2 INT )
    INSERT INTO #t1 
    SELECT 'Row1',1, NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Row2', 1, 2
```

Master Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #t2 ( f1 INT, f2 INT, f3 INT, f4 VARCHAR(255)  ) 

INSERT INTO #t2 
SELECT 1, 2, 3, 'A' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 2, 4, 'B' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 3, 3, 'C' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 3, 4, 'D' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 3, 4, 'E'
```

I want the output to link Row1 to Rows A,B,C and D and Row2 to Rows A and B.  I can achieve this by:

```
SELECT a.f3, b.* 
FROM   #t2 b 
       CROSS JOIN #t1 a 
WHERE  Patindex(Isnull(CONVERT(CHAR(1), a.f1), '_') + Isnull(CONVERT(CHAR(1), a.f2), '_')
                , CONVERT(CHAR(1), b.f1) + CONVERT(CHAR(1), b.f2)) != 0 

DROP TABLE #t1 
DROP TABLE #t2
```

This is not a very scale-able solution, as It will turn into long and complex SQL when I have 20 fields.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: So, you want to require matching ("=") on corresponding columns if the input has a value for that column, but skip that column (i.e., treat it as a wildcard) if it's NULL?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is "one trick" of the trade.

Update all columns, but if no value (a null value) is given for the potential update value....ignore it and use the original value....using a CASE statement.

Your language in your original post is a little confusing.

I think by "fields" you mean "columns".......(I'm not nitpicking, I trying to distinquish between column(s) and "values-in-the-column".)

Maybe the below can help.

Here is a generic Northwind example

```
Use Northwind
GO



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderDetailsHolder') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #OrderDetailsHolder
end


CREATE TABLE #OrderDetailsHolder
(
IdentityKey int not null identity (1001, 1), 
[OrderID] int, 
[ProductID] int,
[UnitPrice] money
)


INSERT INTO #OrderDetailsHolder ( OrderID, ProductID , UnitPrice ) 
Select top 10 OrderID, ProductID , UnitPrice from dbo.[Order Details] where UnitPrice IS NOT NULL


print 'Before massaged data look'
select * from #OrderDetailsHolder

Update #OrderDetailsHolder Set [UnitPrice] = null where IdentityKey < 1006
Update #OrderDetailsHolder Set [UnitPrice] = ([UnitPrice] * 1.333) where IdentityKey >= 1006


print 'After massaged data look'
select * from #OrderDetailsHolder


/* 
Here is the magic (below query).  
If [UnitPrice] is NULL in the "holder" temp table, then KEEP THE ORIGINAL value.  
If the UnitPrice is NOT null in the temp table, update using the holder-temp table UnitPrice value.
*/

Update dbo.[Order Details] 
Set [UnitPrice] = CASE
                    WHEN holder.[UnitPrice] IS NOT NULL then holder.UnitPrice
                    ELSE realTable.UnitPrice
                END
FROM    
    #OrderDetailsHolder holder , dbo.[Order Details] realTable
Where
    holder.OrderID = realTable.OrderID and holder.ProductID = realTable.ProductID



/* Now show the real table data, which should have 5 rows as having different UnitPrice values */

Select * from   #OrderDetailsHolder holder join dbo.[Order Details] realTable
    on holder.OrderID = realTable.OrderID and holder.ProductID = realTable.ProductID






IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderDetailsHolder') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #OrderDetailsHolder
end
```